# Laravel Voyager-Deletion of table fields does not delete from view

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am working on a very simple web application and managing admin panel using *Laravel Voyager Version: 1.1* and *Laravel Version 5.7*.
I have created *Courses* table using Voyager database tool. There is a column by the name of *tutor_id* in *Courses* table.
It was working fine but after few days due to application requirements I have *deleted* that “tutor_id” column from "Courses" table using Voyager. The column has successfully deleted from table which I can see by going to phpMyAdmin.
The issue is that when I browse Courses the tutor_id column is still present there as shown in the figure. 
[image]
I have cleared the cache but have no luck.

Answer (score 0):

1)  go to table `data_types` and find  id of "Courses" table
2)  go to table `data_rows` and find "tutor_id" row and delete it